# Prove that $x^2 + y^2 \equiv 3\,mod\,m$ has and integer solution for every m

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I am struggling with this proof:
Prove that $x^2 + y^2\equiv 3\,mod\,m$ has and integer solution for all m.  I have tried: setting x or y to zero.  Can't do that because then the solution wouldn't be integer.  I have also tried to make $x^2 + y^2 = 3$, which would give me the proof for all m, but again I am unable to get an integer solution.  Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Maybe it holds for primes. For $m=2$, just choose $x=0, y=1$, and $x=y=0$ for $m=3$. For a general prime $p>3$, you could, for example, want to find $x, y$ such that $x^2=ap + 1$ and $y^2=bp+2$ for some $a, b\ge0$. Fermat's little theorem tells us that $z^{p-1}\equiv1\text{ (mod }p)$ if $x$ is not divisible by $p$. Since $p$ is odd, $p-1 = 2k$ for some $k$, and hence $x=z^k$ gives you $x^2\equiv1\text{ (mod }p)$. There could be something similar that would produce you 2.

Comment: Nah, that will probably not work.

Comment: @NelliKuukeri $x^2 \equiv 2 \pmod{p}$ for $ p$ odd has solutions iff $ p \equiv \pm 1 \pmod{8}$.

Comment: So it could be done in that case. Nice.

Answer (score 2):

This is not true for *all* integers $m$. For example, consider $m = 4$. Since squares are congruent to $0$ or $1$ modulo $4$, the sum of $2$ squares can only be congruent to $0$, $1$ or $2$ modulo $4$, so there's *no* solution for $x$ and $y$ in

$$x^2 + y^2 \equiv 3 \pmod 4 \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

Comment: $m=3$ also does not have any integer solution, since it will be either $0$ or $2$ mod $3$

Comment: @RezhaAdrianTanuharja Actually, for $m = 3$, you will get $x^2 + y^2 \equiv 3 \equiv 0 \pmod 3$, which works for $x$ and $y$ both being divisible by $3$.

Comment: Ah right what was I talking about